# Cannot open database "DataDir" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: sql-server

I have a single user software that uses SQL Server database 2005. My computer was crushed while my software was on. I saved a copy of my database after I rescued my computer. However my software gives my following message. ( I don't know anything about SQL) However, I guess my database has the last login information. Since software was not shot down properly, it still thinks that I am logged in doesn't allow me to login again.  How can I solve the problem? Can you help me? Or do you know any source that I can get help?

Cannot open database "DataDir" requested by the login. The login failed
ComputerName = GURELS
User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=DataDir;Data Source=GURELS\CSS;Application Name=ChefTec

User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=CTDir;Data Source=GURELS\CSS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Application Name=ChefTec;Workstation ID=GURELS;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False

Thank you very much

Turkan
e-mail" turkancaglar@yahoo.com
phone:617 259 6644

Comment: you should remove your phone number and personal email address

Answer (score 0):

If you had to reinstall the server, you will likely have orphaned users.
Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475(SQL.90).aspx) for more details.

Comment: doesnt make sense on account of sa is the default admin account

Comment: Hi Chris,
Thank you very much for your respond. It seems that the link that you gave me has the solution. However, since I don't know anything about SQL a friend of mine will help me.. ]
You have a great day...
All the best
Turkan

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure DataDir exists, if it doesn't than thats the problem.  If it does exist I will look into a different solution